Understanding the commandment to build a Temple
Rambam lists building the Beit HaMikdash as a positive commandment (#20) based on the pasuk in Shemot 25:8 - וְעָשׂוּ לִי מִקְדָּשׁ וְשָׁכַנְתִּי בְּתוֹכָם
However, when David requests to build the Temple (2 Shmuel 7) the answer isn't an automatic "yes".
My understanding is that Chazal (eg Sanhedrin 20b, based on Devarim 12:10-11) see the Beit HaMikdash as the fulfillment of a biblical command. However, that doesn't seem to be the straightforward reading of the verses in Shmuel. Working on the assumption that building the Beit HaMikdash is a fulfillment of the biblical command leads to several questions in the text such as:

If it was a biblical command why would David need to ask?
Why would God answer that he cannot do it? (Answers
regarding David having blood on his hands are not based on the text
in Samuel and don't seem to apply to Nehemiah who also has blood on his hands and rebuilds the
Temple)
Why didn't anyone before David even talk about doing building a Beit HaMikdash if it was a biblical mitzvah?
Aren't the verses cited by the Talmud making reference to the Tabernacle?

On the other hands, assuming that building the Beit HaMikdash is not a biblical commandment leads to other problems, such as the fact that a prophet cannot add a new commandment (see Temura 16a) in which case Solomon would not have been allowed to build the Temple either.
Do any commentators explain how to understand the commandment to build a permanent Temple as being biblical in light of the difficulties in the plain reading of 2 Samuel 7?

The place of the Temple had been revealed only to David. It was not revealed to anyone before him.

(1) "If it was a biblical command why would David need to ask?" Maybe because he didn't know if safety was granted from Israel's enemies. Devarim 12:10-11 says: "...and [God] grants you safety from all your enemies around you and you live in security, then you must bring everything that I command you to the site where your God ה' will choose to establish the divine name..." (2) "Why would God answer that he cannot do it?" Maybe because David had yet to defeat Israel's enemies? In 2 Shmuel 8, after requesting to build the Temple, and being declined, david goes off to fight yet more battles.

"Why didn't anyone before David even talk about doing building a Beit HaMikdash if it was a biblical mitzvah?" Maybe because they hadn't been granted [even temporary] safety from all the enemies around them (2 Samuel 7:1)?

"On the other hands, assuming that building the Beit HaMikdash is not a biblical commandment leads to other problems, such as the fact that a prophet cannot add a new commandment (see Temura 16a) in which case Solomon would not have been allowed to build the Temple either." By that logic, at least according to Rambam, Israel would not have been allowed to settle in the Land. Maybe it was [some sort of] a Hora'at Shaah, like Eliyahu making an alter outside the temple, after the temple's been built.

https://toratemple.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2024/11/%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94-%D7%A1%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A2-%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%9C%D7%90-%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9.pdf
